# Modifying HTML string with regex

Tags: javascript

I need help with removing attributes from tags of HTML string for example

```
<div remove="value" class="test"></div>
```

I'm trying to remove the tag with regex

```
(htmlStr.replace(new Regexp('remove="value"','g'),"").
```

The end Output i want is`<div class="test"></div>`

Comment: I need to keep the HTML only remove some attributes

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: A tag `<div...></div>` or an attribute `value="1"`?

Comment: I only want to remove some attributes from the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given such HTML:

```
<div remove="value" class="test" data-color="red"></div>
```

You can replace certain attributes (e.g. `remove` and `data-color`) with such regexp.

```
htmlStr.replace(/ [remove|data\-color]*?=".*?"/g, "")
```

Outputs:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```